# Java XMPP Server

Tags: java, android, client, xmpp

I want to write an Android application where a user can talk to their phone via xmpp over their local WiFi network.  The reason I have chosen XMPP is so that they can use any client software such as Pidgin, Miranda etc..

The communication will only be between the app and the client so ideally what I would like is for a client program such as Pidgin to be able to connect to my app and send and receive messages.  For this I think I would need to write a very lightweight XMPP server in Java within my application for the client to connect to.
I have found alot of information on SO about various XMPP servers (OpenFire etc) however they're geared for more commercial implementation and whereas on a server I could just not use the features in this instance I simply don't have the space.  Also I can't seem to find any libraries for an XMPP server, there is alot of client side libraries like SMACK but nothing I can see for server side.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about this?  IS there a way to emulate an XMPP server using Java?

Comment: It is not really clear to me if you want to run a XMPP *server* instance on Android (and if so why)? Servers aren't usually implemented as lightweight library. The purpose you are trying to achieve (send and receive SMS messages, control the Android phone) seems similar to what [GTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms) does.

Comment: Except that GTalkSMS uses the Google Talk is a client connected to the Google Talk servers.. I want to connect directly to the phone from an XMPP Client program such as Pidgin

Comment: Not true, you can use GTalkSMS with any XMPP compliant server. And by *not using* link-local (aka. serverless) XMPP it also works if you forgot you Android device in your car. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [Serverless XMPP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html).  I am not sure what libraries may have support for this though.

As for using an embedded server in Android, there are several Java servers available (like Openfire and Tigasse), but I don't think you will have much luck trying to install them on Android.  You would most likely be much better off looking for, or implementing the aforementioned Serverless XMPP extension.

I am sure it would be much simpler to have a more typical setup with an actual central server though.  You may want to add why this isn't desirable.

Comment: That looks kind of like what I am looking for however I also want the ability for the server to provide a roster to the client as well.  The application I want to develop will allow you view sms' on your pc as im's and reply.  To be able to integrate this into existing xmpp client software I will need to provide a server within the application for them to connect to.  Thanks for you reply btw.